# How to parallel run multiple npm scripts in rollup watch mode using yarn workspaces foreach?

Tags: node.js, npm, parallel-processing, yarnpkg, watch

I have a React multimodule project.
Every module is built with rollup and has its commands defined as

```
"build": "rollup -c",
"watch": "rollup -cw"
```

From the main `package.json` I have this scripts section:

```
"watch:all": "npm-run-all build:shared --parallel watch:shared watch:a watch:b",
"watch:a": "yarn w:a watch",
"watch:b": "yarn w:b watch",
"watch:shared": "yarn w:shared watch",
"build:shared": "yarn w:shared build"
```

Since the modules `a` and `b` depend both on the `shared` module, I build the shared package first, in order to have my dependencies satisfied, and then I watch everything in parallel, so it is easy to develop. This works fine, but obliges me to build the shared package BEFORE watching all.

I want to use the [yarn workspaces foreach](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/workspaces/foreach) command instead of the `npm-run-all` package, because it can with the `-t` flag wait for the packages that depend on others. This in fact works nicely when I do

```
yarn workspaces foreach -Rpvti --from "{@company/shared,@company/a,@company/b}" run build
```

But when I do

```
yarn workspaces foreach -Rpvti --from "{@company/shared,@company/a,@company/b}" run watch
```

the shared package is correctly built as you can see from the logs:

```
➤ YN0000: [@company/shared]: Process started
➤ YN0000: [@company/shared]: (node:6013) ExperimentalWarning: Importing JSON modules is an experimental feature and might change at any time
➤ YN0000: [@company/shared]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
➤ YN0000: [@company/shared]: rollup v4.12.1
➤ YN0000: [@company/shared]: bundles src/index.ts → lib/esm/index.js, lib/cjs/index.js...
➤ YN0000: [@company/shared]: created lib/esm/index.js, lib/cjs/index.js in 3s
```

But then it remains stuck here and it doesn't proceed at all.
I really can't understand why it is doing such a weird behavior.